# ¿Por qué el textArea no me toma el resto de la información?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Estoy intentando mostrar la información en un textArea, en el método ingresar me muestra todos los datos, pero en el método procesar luego de hacer todas las operaciones solo me toma el primer dato, llevo un rato buscando y no se que pueda ser, no se si hay algún método para mandar la información a un textArea de la forma en que lo hago (utilizando varias veces el método appendtext ) o si se debe si o si mandar uno con toda la información  :

```
@FXML
private TextField txt_Nombre;

@FXML
private TextField txt_Municipio;

@FXML
private TextField txt_Tipo_de_agua;

@FXML
private TextField txt_Id;

@FXML
private TextField txt_Tipo_de_cuerpo_de_agua;

@FXML
private TextField txt_Irca;

@FXML
private Button btn_Ingresar;

@FXML
private Button btn_Procesar;

@FXML
private TextArea txta_Mostrar;

@FXML
private TextArea txta_Mostrar_Proceso;

@FXML
void Ingresar(ActionEvent event) { // Captura de datos para luego mostrar en el primer textArea y mandarlos al vector de tipo objeto
    nombre = txt_Nombre.getText(); 
    municipio = txt_Municipio.getText();
    tipo_De_Agua = txt_Tipo_de_agua.getText();
    id = Integer.parseInt(txt_Id.getText());
    Tipo_de_cuerpo_de_agua = txt_Tipo_de_cuerpo_de_agua.getText();
    irca = Double.parseDouble(txt_Irca.getText());
    txta_Mostrar.setText(nombre + "\n" + id + "\n" + municipio + "\n" + tipo_De_Agua + "\n" + Tipo_de_cuerpo_de_agua
            + "\n" + irca);

    vector[cont] = new CuerpoDeAgua(nombre, id, municipio, tipo_De_Agua, Tipo_de_cuerpo_de_agua, irca);
    cont += 1;

}

@FXML
void Procesar(ActionEvent event) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {// mostrar todos los nombres + el nivel IRCA
        nombre = vector[i].getNombre() + " " + String.format("%.2f", vector[i].getIrca());
        txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(nombre);
        txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        if (vector[i].getIrca() >= 50) { // mostrar cuantos son mayor a 50
            cont_Mayor50 += 1;
        }
    }
    txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(String.format("%.2f", cont_Mayor50));
    txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) { //mostrar cuantos están clasificados como alto encaso contrario mostrar "NA"

        if (vector[i].nivel() == "ALTO") {
            cont_No_Alto += 1;

            txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(vector[i].getNombre() + " ");
            txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        }

        if (vector[i].getIrca() > irca_Mayor) { // capturar el mayor nivel de IRCA
            irca_Mayor = vector[i].getIrca();
        }

    }
    if (cont_No_Alto == 0) {
        txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText("NA");
        txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    }

    // mostrar el mayor nivel de IRCA
    txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText("\n" + String.format("%.2f", irca_Mayor)); 
    txta_Mostrar_Proceso.appendText(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

}
```

}

si hace falta que suba otra parte del código, como la clase principal o la clase CuerpoDeAgua con gusto la subo.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la atención y ayuda prestada

Comment: `appendText()` es obsoleto, debes usar `append()` en su lugar. Si sigue sin funcionar depura tu código, verificando por ejemplo el contenido del vector, su tamaño, etc e imprimiendo lo que supones debería aparecer en el TextArea.